# Gitlab CI/CD : Concat variable in command script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Im my CI/CD configuration pipeline, I have this command in the script of the job :

```
- echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://myproxy:8080";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

I want to replace http://myproxy:8080 (without double quote) with a variable ${MY_VAR} but if i replace the proxy url by the variable, this one is not traduce

```
- echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "${MY_VAR}";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

Ther is simple quote and doubloe quote in the script ... how can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes

```
echo "Acquire::http::Proxy "${MY_VAR}";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

Comment: Thank you It's OK. I have juste add escape char on the double quote arround the variable : echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://${PROXY_SRV}\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf